# How to exclude resource files when lein jar?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

When I run lein jar, it will package my resource files in `src/resources`, but i expect to modify some config files after packaged. So the resource files should be exclude when `lein jar`, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `:jar-exclusions` or `:uberjar-exclusions` in `project.clj` to exclude your config files:

```
;; to exclude all .conf files from jars:
:jar-exclusions [#".*\.conf"]
```

You could also simply not put those files in the resources directory and tell your application where to look for them using, say, an environment variable.